# Opening directory folder using php

Tags: php, directory, glob, opendir

I am trying to construct my own file directory but I have been stuck on one part for a day and cant figure out how to approach this. When the code below runs i checks if its a file or a directory what i want to achieve is when the code detects thats its a directory when clicked on Open Folder it opens the folder with the list of files that it contains can anyone help me here and give me some kind of idea how to approach this ?

```
echo'<table style="background-color: beige; padding: 10px; border: 1px dashed #999;">';
echo'<tr>
<th>File Name</th>
<th colspan="3">Action</th>
</tr>';
foreach(glob('language/*') as $filename){
if ($filename != 'connect.php' && $filename != 'edit.php' && $filename != 'index.php' && $filename != 'nbproject'){
if(is_file($filename)){
echo'<tr>
<td>'.$filename.'</td>
<td><a href="'.$filename.'" name="ru">RU</a></td>
<td><a href="'.$filename.'" name="eng">ENG</a></td>
<td><a href="'.$filename.'" name="lt">LT</a></td>
</tr>';
var_dump($filename);
}
else if(is_dir($filename)){
echo '<tr>
<td>'.$filename.'</td>
<td colspan="3"><a href="'.$filename .'" name="open" >Open Folder</a><td>
</tr>';
}
}
}
echo'</table>';
```

I am thinking i can achieve this with `opendir` function or `glob` function am I on the 
right track ? tnx for the help.

**P.S.**
One more question I am using `glob` to read my directory is `readdir` better to achieve this or is there no difference ? And feel free to point out any other flaws in my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the form tag. You should pass a variable containing the folder name directly from the href property of a tags. e.g.

```
<a href="myscript.php?folder=<?php echo $foldername ?>"><?php echo $foldername ?></a>
```

Be sure to properly check that the directory the user is trying to open is safe to access or you will have nasty security consequences.